# Access VBA Run Time Error 2465: Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form named UI(Navigation Form) in MS Access 2010. I have two more subforms SEARCH and RESULTS as tabbed forms in UI. After I search in SEARCH form, when I click the RESULTS tab I want the value from a combo box named 'cmbID' in SEARCH to be displayed in a label named 'lblAIPIDDisp' in RESULTS form and then display additional labels. So, I gave the following code in the navigation Button Click Event:

```
Private Sub NavigationButton32_Click()
Form_RESULTS.lblAIPIDDisp.Caption = [Forms]![UI]![SEARCH].cmbID.Value
End Sub
```

But I get Run Time Error 2465. So, I tried searching in SEARCH form separately and gave the following code in Form Load Event of RESULTS form:

```
Private Sub Form_Load() 
Form_RESULTS.lblAIPIDDisp.Caption = [Forms]![SEARCH].cmbID.Value
End Sub
```

Now, I searched in SEARCH Form and clicked on RESULTS form. I was able to see the value in Combo Box 'cmbID' in SEARCH Form in the label 'lblAIPIDDisp' in RESULTS Form. So, I think there is something wrong in referencing subforms RESULTS and SEARCH in the Navigation Form UI. Help needed in this point.